# Matlab Simulink Model of nonlinear Model

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-guide

I'm trying to create a Matlab simulink model of the following equation:

[image: Equation 1]

I am very new to simulink and need some help getting started.

Comment: There are multiple sites to "get you started". As far as it stands the question is not stated in an answerable way. It is not a question but a tuition request. It is deemed to be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this is very easy to do.

set the equation so the result is the highest derivative. in you case `d^3y/dt^3`

[image]

There you have. nothing more to do.

How to follow from here you may ask:

you got `x`, and you can derive it, or apply any equation you want to it. The only doubt may come is: *where the hell should i get y from?*

Easy! you have the equation, integrate the result once and use that value for 4*`(dydy/dt^2)^2` , integrate it again and use it for the last item and integrate it again and use it to multiply `x`. That's the advantage of simulink. You can close a loop using the "result" in the equation to calculate the "result" (this is no 100% true, as you use the value of 1 step before in each integration, but it works).

This is the power of simulink, still I strongly recommend you to read a bit about it, so you can understand why to use simulink, but I think playing with it is necessary to learn so: go!

Answer (score 1):

In general when setting up equations in Simulink you should set up a number of integrator blocks to get all your states. When that is done you can sum the different factors together.

Unfortunately I can not post the model I made for the equaltion because of my low reputation points (new here).

```
 dddy          ddy         dy          y
```

+ --------> 1/s ------> 1/s -----> 1/s ----->